# How to find disease association of disgenet with string db in homo sapiens

Tags: proteins, networks, stringdb

I want to work string-db to read the protein-protein interaction from it and I look up disease association from disgenet but the Ids do not seem to match-up and I do not know what to do.

for example for protein `INSR` which is mostly afflicted with diabetes and similar diseases I found that from 'disgenet' but I do not find the ids in string, is the a convertion table some where?

```
protein1 protein2 combined_score
9606.ENSP00000000233 9606.ENSP00000272298 490
```

PS: I think this question may sound stupid to you but I am an absolute noob and would be glad to help me out.